# nativescript and angular2 - no Provider Error

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I've got problem with loading nativescript app using angular2 and typescript. I'm trying to solve for long time. What i have is:

list.service.ts

```
import { ItemListApi } from '../sdk/services/custom/ItemList';
import { ItemList } from '../sdk/models/ItemList';

@Injectable()
export class ListService {
items: Observable<Array<Item>>;
public grocery: Grocery = new Grocery('', '');
private listModel: ItemList = new ItemList();

constructor(private itemListApi: ItemListApi,
    private authModelApi: AuthModelApi,
    private loginCredentials: LoginCredentials) {

}

addItems(list: ItemList) {
    let uid;
       uid = this.loginCredentials.getUserId();
         return this.itemListApi.create({
        "name": list.name,
        "userid": uid
    });
};
}
```

module.ts

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
CommonModule,
FormsModule,
RouterModule
],
declarations: [
LoginComponent,
ListComponent
],
providers: [
LoginService,
ListService,
LoginCredentials,
HeroActions,
HeroService
],
exports: [
LoginComponent,
ListComponent
]
})
```

All the time I'm getting error message saying "No provider for ItemListApi" ...
actually ItemListApi is from my loopback nativescript sdk.
can someone help me spot that small issue with my code?

Comment: you should provide the service as a rpvoider in the component where it is used ..see there for example https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/blob/master/app/http/http-get/http-get.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

Add `ItemListApi` into your `app.module.ts`'s provider list:

```
providers: [
LoginService,
ListService,
LoginCredentials,
HeroActions,
HeroService,
ItemListApi
],
```

In reply to what Nick said, he cant add it as a provider in the ts file he's in as he is using `@Injectable` not `@Component`

Comment: actually this module.ts is shared file that is it is common for web,desktop and nativescript app. so whatever chages i made in this file will reflect to all in app.i have 2 sdk one for web and one for nativecsript. this nativescript sdk ItemListApi getting this error. so  what should i do?

Comment: Well adding `ItemListApi` should solve your problem so I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments; you need to update your imports in the module.ts file.

Add:

```
import { SDKBrowserModule } from './shared/sdk/index';
```

with the other imports in your module.ts, then also:

```
SDKBrowserModule.forRoot()
```

in your imports array in module.ts